# Need Help To Make Counter Clickable Between 12noon-2pm

Tags: javascript, html, counter

I am currently using this counter button for my banner rotation. I need help to make it clickable between 12noon and 2pm. Below is the script I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction(){
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
    setTimeout (function(){
        document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = null;
    },15000);

    var countdownNum = 15;
    incTimer();

    function incTimer(){
        setTimeout (function(){
            if(countdownNum != 0){
                countdownNum--;
                document.getElementById('timeLeft').innerHTML = 'Wait! Time Left: ' + countdownNum + ' seconds';
                incTimer();
            } else {
                document.getElementById('timeLeft').innerHTML = 'Click To Rotate Banner Now!';
            }
        },1000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the actual question here? Have you tried anything yourself? I see zero code related to getting the current time.

Comment: I am unable to edit this Q.  Please format your code correctly so it is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

listen all the click and if it's between 12noon and 2pm do something

```
var doSomething = function(){
    //do something 
}

var checkIfBetweenWhatWeWant = function(){
    var d = new Date(),
     hour = d.getHours();

    //sorry i'm from europe i don't know how to "date" with 12hour system
    if( 00 <= hour && hour <= 13) {
        doSomething();
    }

}

var elem = document.getElementById('IdElemYouWantToClickOn');
elem.addEventListened('click',checkIfBetweenWhatWeWant,false);
```

sorry for variable's name :D